# How to read PDF files from assets sub folder in android

Tags: android, pdf, assets

I have pdf files which are placed in assets sub folder. Iam showing the pdf files in the form of a list  view.When clicking on any list items ,it shows an error,"Pdf cannot be displayed,Path error".How to set path for sub folder in assets???

Thanks in Advance!

Here is my class.Please check the code below
[image]

```
public class PdfViewInformation extends Activity{

ListView pdflist;
String  itemValue;
String valueinfo;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.pdfviewinfo);

     AssetManager asset = getAssets();
        try {
            final String[] arrdata = asset.list("pdffolder");
            List<String> pdflist = new ArrayList<String>();
            int size = arrdata.length;
            for(int i = 0;i<size;i++)
            {
              if(arrdata[i].contains(".pdf"))

              {
                pdflist.add(arrdata[i]); 
               }
            }
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter= new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,pdflist);
            ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
                    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
             public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {

                 valueinfo = (String)parent.getItemAtPosition(position); 
                 File file = new File("android.resource://com.example.timesampleexp/assets/pdffolder/"+valueinfo);        
              Log.i("jduhsr", ""+file);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file),"application/pdf");
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    startActivity(intent);




            }


        });
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

     }
```

Comment: can you please show the structure of your assets folder.

Comment: Please check the image above of assets folder...@Ashish Tamrakar

Answer (score 0):

```
        File file = new File("android_asset/subfoldername/"+filename);

       Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file),"application/pdf");
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(intent);
```

You have to insert your sub folder name which you are using and file name in the file path.If you want to view the pdf file you may use already installed pdf reader like adobe reader like the way i mentioned above.otherwise you can load the pdf files in your own application by using libraries like pdf.js

Comment: While the code you've provided may answer the question, it's always best to provide an explanation on why/how it does so.